# Mysql - Getting duplicate results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables UPDATES, MODELS, and UPDATES_MODELS.

The UPDATES table has the following columns:

- update_id,
- posted
- thumbnail

The MODELS table has the following columns:

- model_id
- first_name
- last_name.

The UPDATES_MODELS is a linking table and has the following columns:

- update_id
- model_id.

Some updates have more than 1 model. For example if an update has 2 models, my query will return 2 duplicate thumbnails, 2 duplicate titles,
2 duplicate dates, and 1 update will have 1 model name and the other update will have the other model name.

This is not what I want.

An update with 2 or more models should return 1 thumbnail, 1 title, 1 date and list both model names with the update.

I tried using DISTINCT in SQL query, that did nothing. I got the same result with or without the DISTINCT keyword.

Here's is my code:

```
SELECT updates.update_id, title, posted, duration, updates.thumbnail, updates.alt_tag, updates.title_tag, updates.visible, models.model_id, first_name, last_name, updates_models.update_id, updates_models.model_id
FROM updates
INNER JOIN updates_models
ON updates.update_id = updates_models.update_id
INNER JOIN models
ON models.model_id = updates_models.model_id
```

Comment: Give sample data ang sample result you wanted.

Comment: So you're expecting your SELECT to produce 1 full row (a thumbnail, title, date, and a model), and a second row that only contains a model? Sorry, but that's not going to happen. Handle extracting only the relevant information in your front end app or report.

Comment: Thank you Ken for your input. Are you saying that I need to run 2 SQL queries?

Comment: you can reduce the characters you have to type out in the return columns if you create aliases for your tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I doubt you table model. If you have the case 'Update have multiple Models, but not same Model can own to multiple Update', then it's one to many relation ship and you can just keep update_id in Models table.

Your question is not very clear and incomplete. Your query has columns which you have not explained in the question. However you can try below query for your case if I got you properly with limited details.

```
SELECT updates.update_id,  posted,  updates.thumbnail,array_agg(first_name), array_agg(last_name), updates_models.update_id, updates_models.model_id FROM "UPDATES" updates INNER JOIN "UPDATES_MODELS" updates_models ON updates.update_id = updates_models.update_id INNER JOIN "MODELS" models ON models.model_id = updates_models.model_id group by updates.update_id, posted, updates.thumbnail, updates_models.update_id, updates_models.model_id
```